# Why is Firefox allowing disabling of confirmation boxes?

Tags: javascript, firefox, confirm

Running this example http://jsfiddle.net/yxzqY/ on Firefox on my Mac, about half the confirmation prompts appear with a "prevent this window from creating further dialogs" checkbox. I understand allowing users to disable alerts, but confirmation boxes are part of control flow- clicking OK or Cancel dictates the next sequence of events- and disabling them breaks an application.

I see plenty of applications that rely on confirmation prompts, and have never seen Firefox or any other browser doing this (witness trying to delete a question on StackOverflow)- so why is it occuring here? Why is it happening only sporadically? And how can we prevent it from happening at all?

Comment: Chrome does this too.  It seems like it only happens when you trigger too many boxes (in a short time).

Comment: Rocket- The behavior doesn't seem to align with how many times it's triggered. Try my example a few times and you'll see it. Then click on "delete" on your comment in StackOverflow in rapid fire, and it never shows up. Something else is going on..

Comment: I tested it in Firefox 12 on Windows, and I changed it once per second, and it said "prevent this window from creating further dialogs" on the dialog.  Waiting ~4 seconds seemed to be the sweet spot.

Comment: Don't use `confirm()`. Create your own custom dialog window or use a plugin, there are plenty of options.

Comment: clmarquart- plenty of programs use it (basecamp, stackoverflow)- i don't go out of my way to implement built-in features

Comment: It does seem to have something to do with the time between the dialogs.  Compare these 2 examples: http://jsfiddle.net/6bxWc/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/6bxWc/2/

Comment: A decade later, I stumble on this in a mainstream application. I disabled the prompts, at the moment thinking "I don't need to confirm every one of these operations". But of course the application requires confirmation or it doesn't perform the desired action. So now I'm on the quest to find out how to get the dialogs back! Googled solutions included clearing cache and checking a site-specific setting (couldn't find one). The solution to this is simply to open the app in another tab. YMMV HTH for the next decade...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the criterion for a "prevent further dialogs" checkbox is that the user has been presented with more than one dialog in a row within a short period of time (perhaps five seconds or so in current versions of Firefox; a second or two in Chrome).

The reason it's being added under these circumstances is to prevent malicious pages from tying the user up with endless sequences of dialogs:

```
while(1) {
    alert("Is this annoying yet?");
}
```

If you expect that your application will be using a lot of confirmation dialogs like this, I recommend that you use a DOM dialog (e.g, http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead of the native `alert()` or `confirm()`.

Comment: diskwuff- See my comment to Rocket- it is not dependent on frequency. Click delete/cancel on your answer multiple times, it won't ever happen.

Comment: I was able to trigger a silencing checkbox in Chrome by hammering the delete button on a comment about once a second. (Using the Esc key to cancel the dialog, rather than clicking Cancel, may make it easier to see.)

Comment: hmm- ok, hadn't seen that.. Still, whats happening in my demo seems to be measured by something else- i can't get more than two or three without getting it

Comment: Here's a fiddle that'll also do it: http://jsfiddle.net/VVBYF/ (NB: If your browser doesn't allow you to disable dialogs, this demo will put you in a tight spot!)